# The intersection of all subspace of $V$ is $\{0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-subspace with basis $B=\{v_1 ,v_2, \ldots , v_n\}$ and $\overline{v}\in V$, $\overline{v}\neq 0$.

I have shown that if we exchange $\overline{v}$ with a $v_i\in B$ we get again a basis.

I want to show, using this fact, that the intersection of all subspace of $V$ of dimension $n-1$ is $\{0\}$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We suppose that there is a non-zero vector, say $u$, common to all $(n-1)$-dimensional subspaces.

Then suppose that $B$ is the basis of the intersection, then $u\in B$.

We can exchange $u$ by an other element $v\in V$ and we get again a basis, right?

How can we continue?

Comment: I think you need more conditions to prove the first result. For example $\{ i, j, k\}$ is a basis for three dimensional real space. But if you replace $k$ by $i+j$, the result is not a basis.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is the easiest way to answer your original question. The way to do what you’re asking is:
Asume by contradiction that the intersection has a non zero vector $u$. Complete $u$ to a basis $u, v_2, ....v_n$. Now $v_2, ...,v_n$ spans a $n-1$ subspace. $u$ can’t be an element of that sub space because it’s independent of $v_2, ...,v_n$ by our construction. This leads to the desired contradiction.

Comment: We complete $u$ to a basis: $u, v_2, ....v_n$. So these vectors are linearly independent ans span $V$. Does it hold that if we take $n-1$ of these vectors then they span a $n-1$ subspace? Also I haven't really understood why $u$ can’t be an element of that sub space. And at which point do we use the fact that if we exchange an element of a basis with an other element of $V$ then we get again a basis?

Comment: If n-1 are not independent then the n vectors won’t be independent by definition. So they span a n-1 subspace. u can’t be an element of that subspace because if it was it was there would be a non trivial leaner combination of the other basiS vectors that equals u. Contradicting the fact that u, ... v_n is independent

Answer (score 1):

Let call N "the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ with dimension $n-1$" and $$N_i = \text{span}(B \setminus \{v_i\})$$
Then each $N_i$ is a subspace of $V$ with dimension $n-1$ and ofc it holds $$N \subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^n N_i$$

Now it's pretty clear (or can be seen by induction) that $$N_i \cap N_j = \text{span}(B \setminus \{v_i,v_j\})$$

Hence $$N \subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^n N_i = \text{span}(B \setminus \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}) = \text{span}(\emptyset) = \{0\}$$

Comment: So, we define $N_i$ to be the span of the set $B$ except the element $v_i$. So, the basis of $N_i$ is the set of elements of $B$ except $v_i$, or not? Is $N$ the intersection of $N_i$ ? At which point do we use the fact that if we exchange an element of a basis with an other element of $V$ then we get again a basis?

Comment: Yes exactly. $N$ is in fact the intersection of the $N_i$'s but we don't need this… we just use that $N$ is definitely a subspace of the intersection of all $N_i$ (what's clear by definition of $N$) and get later as a result that it is the same. 
I didn't use (and don't need) that the exchange of an element of the basis is a basis again. Why should I use it if I don't need it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since $B$ is a basis, you have
$$
\bar{v}=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iv_i
$$
and, since $\bar{v}\ne0$, one of the coefficients $\alpha_i$ must be nonzero. Let it be $\alpha_j$. Then
$$
v_j=\frac{1}{\alpha_j}\biggl(\bar{v}-\sum_{i\ne j}\alpha_iv_i\biggr)
$$
implying that $v_j$ belongs to the span of $B'=\{\bar{v},v_1,\dots,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},v_n\}$. Clearly all $v_i$, with $i\ne j$, belong to the span of $B'$, so the span of $B'$ is the same as the span of $B$, that is, $V$. Hence $B'$ is a basis, because it is a spanning set with $n$ elements.

Since $\bar{v}$ does not belong to the span of $\{v_1,\dots,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},v_n\}$ which has dimension $n-1$, you conclude $\bar{v}$ does not belong to every $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace.

---

An easier proof.

Let $u$ be a nonzero vector in $V$. Complete it to a basis $\{u_1=u,u_2,\dots,u_n\}$.

Define $f\colon V\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(u)=1$ and $f(u_i)=0$ for $i=2,\dots,n$.

Then $\ker f$ has dimension $n-1$ and $u\notin\ker f$.

Comment: Do we have that $\bar{v}$ doesn't belong to the span of $\{v_1,\dots,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},v_n\}$ because the element $v_j$ is missing? Since $\bar{v}$ doesn't belong to the span of $\{v_1,\dots,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},v_n\}$, i.e. since $\bar{v}$ doesn't belong to a $(n-1)$-dimension subspace of $V$ it cannot belong to the intersection of all $(n-1)$-dimension subspaces. So, no element can belong in the intersection, and so the intersection is the empty set $\{0\}$. Is everything correct?

Comment: Can we also use the fact that we can we exchange an element of the basis with an other element of V and we get again a basis, to see that $B'$ is also a basis? I mean, we have that $B=\{v_1, \ldots , v_{j-1}, v_j,v_{j+1},\ldots ,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ and if we exachange $v_j$ with $\overline{v}$ we get that $B'=\{\bar{v},v_1,\dots,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},v_n\}$ is also a basis.

Comment: @MaryStar An $n$ element set that spans an $n$-dimensional space is a basis. Of course, no element of a basis belongs to the span of the other elements, by linear independence.

Comment: Ah ok! Can we make it specific when we have a specific vector space? If we take for example $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, we have the basis $B=\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$.  We want the intersection of alle subspaces of dimension 2. Can we find them?

Comment: Are the subspaces of dimension 2 the sets containing combination of 2 vectors of $B$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar No; only a finite number of them are of this form, but there are infinitely many of them when the space has dimension $>2$. However, if the intersection of a finite number of $2$-dimensional subspaces is $\{0\}$, then also the intersection of all the $2$-dimensional subspaces is $\{0\}$.